# get user role value as a string from wp usermeta table into custom script

Tags: user-meta, capabilities

Just came accross while retriving wp_capabilities from `wp_usermeta` table, this returns serialize output `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

When i unserialized, it gives an array

```
Array ( [administrator] => 1 )
```

Since I'll be querying in a foreach loop to prepare a custom user record list, need a way so that for each user i can `echo` the value `administrator` or whatever that belongs to particular user.

Comment: Use `echo key( $user->caps );`

Comment: This question is about basic PHP and is not really WordPress specific. How are you retrieving the data? Post your code, please. Perhaps that will bring the question on-topic.

Comment: @s_ha_dum you are correct!! Even I'm retrieving in a Laravel blade, but since the usermeta table is specific to wordpress, I thought wp ppl may respond quick.

Comment: That just makes this further off topic as you will need a "blade" solution, and harder to debug/answer.